# java while loop inside or outside loop

Tags: java

I have the below code to show when the next leap year is. In the while loop, I didn't have the line inside the while loop `leapYear = (((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0)) || (y % 400 == 0))` at the first attempt. My reason for not including that line was if leapYear false, y will plus 1. And then `while (!leapYear)` condition is tested again using the new y value by plugging into the line above the while loop `boolean leapYear = (((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0)) || (y % 400 == 0))`.

I don't understand why I need to put that leapYear line in the while loop again. I already had it above the loop which will be used to test the condition after `y++` since the while condition requires to test whether leapYear.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NextLeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner year = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a year: ");
        int y = year.nextInt();
        boolean leapYear = (((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0)) || (y % 400 == 0));        
        while (!leapYear) {
            y++; 
            leapYear = (((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0)) || (y % 400 == 0));
        }
        System.out.println("The next leap year is " + y + "."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: One way you can understand is to put a print statement inside the loop, print out the values of `y` and `leapYear` and see how they change as the loop is executed.  A debugger will also help if you have one available; it'll show you the values as the loop executes.  Finally, look up "hand execution" on the internet, I find being able to calculate these sorts of things by hand leads to better understanding.

Comment: "using the new y value by plugging into the line above" - no, that's not how it works at all. `leapYear`'s value has already been calculated and won't be changed unless you explicitly tell it you want it to change. If you want something that changes based on the value it depends on, you might be looking for a **method**.

Comment: Give Bob a piece of candy. If Bob has 2 pieces of candy, give Sarah a piece of candy (he doesn't, so we don't). Give Bob 1 more piece of candy. Sarah doesn't have a piece of candy.

Comment: Thank everyone for the comments and advices. I still don't understand how the while loop process works. After y++, while condition (!leapYear) needs to be tested again. In order to test the condition, ! leapYear needs to be evaluated. In order to calculate the leapYear value, shouldn't the boolean statement that assigns the leapYear variable be used? Therefore, leapYear value is changed because of y++.

Comment: Your calculation is evaluated and then that value is **stored** in the variable `leapyear`. The expression is not stored in the variable; the evaluated result is stored in the variable. The variable then keeps its value (true or false) until it you reassign it something else.

Comment: @khelwood, where the expression is stored if it's not stored in the variable? How does the computer evaluate the assignment of a variable in terms of what hardwares are involved and how they work together to get the value?

Comment: The variable doesn't store the expression. The variable stores the **result of evaluating** the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Because your y is changing inside the loop. leapYear depends on y so you need to re-calculate once y changes.

Comment: When you do the while condition test, doesn't !leapYear get automatically recalculated by using the boolean expression above the loop that assigns the leapYear variable?

Comment: The = sign in programming is not "truth" operator. It is "assignment" operator. A = X + Y does not mean a is always sum of X and Y. It actually means sum up X and Y and assign it to A. The value of A will remain this assigned value unless it is assigned again.

Comment: This kind of computation where A = X + Y always hold true is mostly achieved by analog computers or non-clocked digital circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Y Value Changes inside the loop so, for examples if 1994 is the value of Y. then it is a `leapyear`, Then inside the loop it checks for not leapyear and value of y is pre incremented `++y`. So, now if it is 1995, then it is tested for the condition, i.e !leapyear and a while loop executes until it satisfies the condition, so until the next leapyear which is 1998. so then it terminates and prints the leapyear. Hope this helps.!